# Finding percent string similarity

Tags: python-3.x, string, similarity

I'd like to find the number of matches between two strings so that I can calculate percent similarity. I'd like to do this without having to download anything as this has given me trouble. I tried downloading the biopython zip file and couldn't figure out how to get it setup. I'd like something that I can turn into a function to be easily used for different sequences. Doesn't need to be able to process anything more than say, 50 characters per string.

The sequences that I'm trying to compare are:

```
virX = 'TTTTCTTATTGT'
virZ = 'GTGGCAGACGGT'
virY = 'CTTCCTCACCGA'
virU = 'ATTACCAAAAGA'
```

outputs that I'm looking for are:
1) percent similarity between each sequence
2) two sequences with highest similarity

This worked but is time consuming to adjust to other sequences:

```
dnaA = 'ATATGCC'
dnaB = 'AAAGCGC'

count = 0
if dnaA[0] == dnaB[0]:
    count +=1
if dnaA[1] == dnaB[1]:
    count +=1
if dnaA[2] == dnaB[2]:
    count +=1
if dnaA[3] == dnaB[3]:
    count +=1
if dnaA[4] == dnaB[4]:
    count +=1
if dnaA[5] == dnaB[5]:
    count +=1
if dnaA[6] == dnaB[6]:
    count +=1

print(count, (count / len(dnaA) * 100), '%')
```

I tried this, which didn't work:

```
count = 0
for i in dnaA:
    if i == dnaB[i]:
        count += 1
```

I tried this:

```
from itertools import izip
def hamming_distance(str1, str2):
    assert len(str1) == len(str2)
    return sum(chr1 != chr2 for chr1, chr2 in izip(str1, str2))

print(hamming_distance(dnaA, dnaB))
```

which returned the error:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/mac03/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Wk5FriLab.py",
>   line 79, in 
>       from itertools import izip ImportError: cannot import name 'izip' from 'itertools' (unknown location)"

I attempted to change `izip` to `zip`, this didn't work. I also tried this function in the jupyter notebook and was given the error:

> "ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         5 
>         6 
>   ----> 7 from itertools import zip
>         8 def hamming_distance(str1, str2):
>         9     assert len(str1) == len(str2)
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'zip' from 'itertools' (unknown
>   location)"

I tried these inputs and recieved errors as well:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

> "  File "", line 6
>       python -m ensurepip I'm                       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

```
pip install pip --upgrade
```

> "  File "", line 7
>       pip install pip --upgrade
>                 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

```
pip install biopython
```

> "   File "", line 7
>       pip install biopython
>                 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: where did you use "pip" command? in terminal or python shell?

Comment: In IDLE, not the shell. So I guess that would the terminal? Should I have used the shell?

Comment: No. you did it right. should be run in terminal not python shell.

Comment: I was able to get this to work when I pasted pip code into IDLE and saved as a .py. Then opened the windows terminal, directed to the folder, and executed the file. Then from windows terminal I entered pip commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for calculating "count" (I assumed strings length are equal):

```
dnaA = 'ATATGCC'
dnaB = 'AAAGCGC'
count = 0
indexB = 0
for i in dnaA:
  if i == dnaB[indexB]:
    count +=1
  indexB +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dnaA = 'ATATGCC'
dnaB = 'AAAGCGC'
matches = [
    nucl_A == nucl_B
    for nucl_A, nucl_B in zip(dnaA, dnaB)
]
similarity = sum(matches)/len(matches)
similarity
```

Result: `0.42857142857142855`

As a function:

```
def hamming_dist(gene_a, gene_b):  
    matches = [
        nucl_a == nucl_b
        for nucl_a, nucl_b in zip(gene_a, gene_b)
    ]
    return sum(matches)/len(matches)
```